# Remove Ad banner

Tags: support, ios

in Tor browser how do I remove the ad banner that prevents me from accessing the bottom of the browser screen because I can not enter or select certain items placed at the bottom of page. Is there a pay version of Tor without advertising?

Tor browser download from apple store
Configuration : iPad, iOs 7.0.4

[image]

Comment: Could you please make a screenshot of that banner and update the question? Websites may contain advertisement and the TorBrowser displays them, but the TorBrowser itself does not include the banner on its own. To my knowledge the Tor Project does not finance itself by any advertisement or affiliation program.

Comment: Screenshot added and config infos added.

Comment: Is this what you're using? https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tor-browser/id712805884?mt=8 It uses Tor, and presents itself as being official, but I don't think it's actually affiliated with the Tor project.

Comment: yes it is this app (on the french store but il's the same)
https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/tor-browser/id712805884?mt=8 I thought it was an official browser as a link for assistance refers to https://www.torproject.org/

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not official. It's just some guy trying to make a quick buck off other's work

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your help ( I don't know if i'm right to answer like that but it's too hard for me to understand the "help usage guide" of this site.

Answer (score 2):

This app was already identified as fake. In the public bug tracker you'll find [report #10549](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/10549). A complaint was filed at 26th December 2013. It is unclear how and when Apple will react.  I can only recommend to *not* use this app.

Answer (score -3):

This app is real. It connects to the Tor network and allows access to dark net sites. You can't remove adds from the app (since it's an app)